# Facebook API - how to handle profile without a vanity url?

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook, api

I'm working on an AS3 Flash only facebook app - and I'm confused about how to download the users picture when a vanity url is not in use.

Once authorized - i'm able to access the basic information fine first_name, last_name (not profile pic tho).. but I do recieve the link which can come in 2 forms

```
1.with vanity url ie. 
http://www.facebook.com/mynickname

2. without vanityurl ie.
http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100000462568669
```

when 1. is in effect, I can access the remote profile picture fine via..

```
service.url = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+nickname+"?fields=picture";
```

but I don't know how to for case 2 - anyone seen this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the ID and vanity name are interchangeable.

[`http://graph.facebook.com/StevenLevy?fields=picture`](http://graph.facebook.com/StevenLevy?fields=picture)

is the same as

[`http://graph.facebook.com/534895623?fields=picture`](http://graph.facebook.com/534895623?fields=picture)

---

Note: You may also be able to just use [`http://graph.facebook.com/534895623/picture`](http://graph.facebook.com/StevenLevy/picture) if you're just looking for profile pictures.

Answer (score -1):

After a question mark you have to use the ampersand (&) for other variables.

`service.url = "http://graph.facebook.com/profile.php?id="+id+"&fields=picture";`